# Ant referencing classes in zip

Tags: ant, zip

Just had a quick question, in my ant build.xml, when I am stating where my jar's that need to be included are located, is it possible to include a .zip file with the classes i need in there as well? Only reason I am asking is because I have received classes that I am dependent on from an outside source and they are just zipped up. I was thinking something like this could be possible.

```
<path id="test.lib">
      <fileset dir="{basedir}/../path/to/lib/files" includes="testzip.zip" />
</path>
```

I just wasn't sure if the classes had to be in jar format. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not. The zip extension is fine.

Comment: Will do, had to wait 3 minutes for some reason hah.